# HTTP Request not working in AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, request, afnetworking

I am attempting to turn this HTTP API Call into an Objective-C using AFNetworking.

```
GET /api/call?action=helloWorld&query=... HTTP/1.1
Host: www.volunteermatch.org
Accept-Charset: UTF-8
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: WSSE profile="UsernameToken"
X-WSSE:UsernameToken Username="acme",
PasswordDigest="quR/EWLAV4xLf9Zqyw4pDmfV9OY=", Nonce=
"d36e316282959a9ed4c89851497a717f", Created="2003-12-15T14:43:07-0700"
```

Here is what I am attempting to do, however I am receiving no data.

```
NSDictionary* param = @{
                        @"action":@"helloWorld",
                        @"query":@"{\"name\":\"john\"}"
                        };

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.volunteermatch.org/"]];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"WWSE profile=\"UsernameToken\"" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:[CocoaWSSE headerWithUsername:@"XXX" password:@"XXXXX"] forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-WSSE"];

[manager GET:@"api/call" parameters:param success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject)
 {
     // Success
     NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);
 }failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error)
 {
     // Failure
     NSLog(@"Failure: %@", error);
 }];
```

Here is what result I was expected to return, however I am receiving nothing.

```
{
 "name": "john",
 "result": "Hello john!"
}
```

Comment: Does your request work if sent with, say, curl? Are you sure it's not a server problem? What do your NSErrors say?

Comment: @Kreiri there is no NSerror it simply gives back a 200 code with a null response